# How to return a value from ansible playbook to an shell script?

Tags: shell, ansible

I call a playbook from a shell script , example

```
#!/bin/bash
UPGRADE=`ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/hosts checkUpgrade.yml`
echo " UPGRADE VALUE $UPGRADE "
```

I want to return/set some variable from checkUpgrade.yml, so that my caller script can use it for further use.

Note: Don't want to write the value to file

Comment: Despite your wishes, writing a value to the file is really the best way to accomplish what you want.  Alternately, call your script *from* the ansible playbook, in which case you could just pass it an argument on the command line.

Comment: Why would you use Ansible to get some single value?

Comment: Pipe the output to grep and store it.  This is more a `shell` question.

Answer (score 1):

[Registering Variables for later use in playbooks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables)

[Using registered variables in conditionals](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_conditionals.html#register-variables)

[Reading Registered variable Return Values](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/common_return_values.html)

---

If you register a variable on a command or shell, the return code is always(?) saved.

More specific to your apparent use, have the end of the playbook output some key sentinel string that you can scan for in $UPGRADE.

```
if grep -q SPECIAL_CONDITION_1 <<< "$UPGRADE"
then doStuff1
elif grep -q SPECIAL_CONDITION_2 <<< "$UPGRADE"
then doStuff2
...
```

ways to make more efficient, but this should make the point.

Comment: Edited my syntax.